# MediaDevices.getUserMedia() on IOS, android native app by ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, webrtc, getusermedia, mediadevices

I've made `voicecalling/videocalling/screensharing` app for browser by `webRTC/node.js/socket.io`
And making **PWA application** for mobile users by `ionic` now.

Then, I can get user's (`video` and so on) track using `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` on basic `browser app and pwa`
But unable to get on `IOS`, **android native app** created by `ionic`.

Maybe, I guess this is since `MediaDevices` is `webAPI`, and `ionic` is not supposed to translate for that. But I'm not sure, I have really limited knowledge about this.

does someone know there is possible way? Or simply it is impossible with **ionic**?

Thank you very much